# How to make use of presto jdbc connection pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, connection-pooling, presto

Wanted to check how to use Presto JDBC connection pool. We have a spring boot application where we have to query Database through presto using JDBC calls frequently, and we don't want to create a new connection per request. Instead, we want to maintain a pool of connections.

Is there any option to maintain connection pool?

My current code to do connection:

```
       try {
            // Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver");
            // Open a connection
            conn = (PrestoConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);
            conn.setTimeZoneId("UTC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't make a connection to Presto DB. error: " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: Spring Boot comes with a connection pool built-in. If you use the right configuration, you might already be using it. So, show how you configure and create your connections.

Comment: I added the connection code above to question details

Comment: I suggest that you read the [spring boot documentation on how to properly configure database connections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-sql). Using `DriverManager` directly in web applications is a bit of an anti-pattern.

Comment: Sounds good, I used HikariDataSource instead of DriverManager, and I set MaximumPoolSize. Then i getConnection from the HikariDataSource.